# php regex grab the end of the next line

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex `Bachelors+([^\r\n]+)` and I am able to grab that line, what do I add so I can grab the entire next line?

Here is the text

```
Bachelors of Science in Computer Science                                     2001
Boston University, College of Science and Engineering
```

Here is a link to regex101.
https://regex101.com/r/dQ0gR6/89

I am able to grab everything until the end of 2001, how do I grab the entire next line?

Comment: Try [`Bachelors([^\r\n]+)[\r\n].*`](https://regex101.com/r/08Mwy8/1) Note that the `s+` repeats an `s` one or more times in your regex.

Comment: You can use: [`/Bachelors(.*)\R(.*)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/dQ0gR6/91)

Comment: Use `/(*ANY)Bachelors.+\R.+/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bachelors[^\n]+\n([^\n]+)
```

The key is using a negative character class.  Which in this case is any character not a newline `[^\n]`

It can be demoed here where you can tweak it as you see fit:
https://regex101.com/r/18dECw/1

Comment: Note that `[^\n]` aso matches CR.